# What exactly means Indy underlying error 14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, indy, delphi-10-seattle

What exactly happens in Indy when a simple HTTPS request from a browser causes the debugger to break with this error:

> Project PMS_COM.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error accepting connection with SSL.
>
> error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown'.

Some on the Internet say that this is a client certificate error, but there is no client certificate! There is only the server-side certificate.

But if I understood wrong and it is a client-side error, then why does it cause an exception on the server side?

Additionally I don't understand how to intercept such kind of errors. `EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError` seems to happen somewhere in Indy with no chance to catch it in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError` is an Indy exception wrapping an OpenSSL error message.

Per [SSLv3 alert certificate unknown (4279556)](https://support.oneidentity.com/syslog-ng-premium-edition/kb/4279556/sslv3-alert-certificate-unknown):

> The SSL library sends an alert back to the system telling the certificate chain was invalid.
>
> The message section that says "sslv3 alert certificate unknown" usually refers to the intermediate certificate in a chain of certificates. That certificate is expired, invalid or not trusted by one or more systems involved in the SSL/TLS communication.

In this case, the *client* (browser) is sending an alert to your server to abort the TLS handshake because your server certificate is invalid.  That alert is triggering the `EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError` exception within the server's code.  The server will handle the error for you, by closing its end of the TCP connection that failed the handshake, and terminate/recycle the worker thread which owns that TCP socket.

If you want to catch the error, you can use the server's `OnException` event, which is triggered in the same thread that owns the TCP connection that failed the TLS handshake.

Comment: Thank you for explanation of inner processes!